# Extjs Load store before the view

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, constructor, store

I have a view which gous like this:

```
Ext.define('Webedi.view.zones.Menu', {
    store: 'PartnerSettings',
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            .
            .
            .
            .
    adminPanelEnabled: false,
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

console.log(Ext.getStore('Userrights').findExact("name","admin_panel_access"));

          if(Ext.getStore('Userrights').findExact("name","admin_panel_access") !== -1) me.adminPanelEnabled = true;
//        if(Ext.getStore('PartnerSettings').getAt(0).get('purchasingOrganisation').enabled ) me.purchasingOrganisationEnabled = true;
        this.items = [
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .

                    {
                        id: 'adminpanel',
                        itemId: 'adminpanel',
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: Translation.ZonesMenuAdminPanel,
                        action: 'adminpanel',
                        margin: '3 3 0 3',
                        hidden: !me.adminPanelEnabled
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

The problem is that

```
 if(Ext.getStore('Userrights').findExact("name","admin_panel_access") !== -1)
```

Is not yet filled on the time when the part of code runs for:

```
 hidden: !me.adminPanelEnabled
```

`initComponent` function Kicks in?

Comment: As you've said, you need to wait. Don't create the view until the store has loaded. Load the store, wait for the callback, then load the view.

Comment: is autoShow: true, the culprit in this case?

Comment: No, initComponent is called before. You need to wait until the sote finished loading before creating the view.

Comment: Possibly, you don't show `autoShow` in your example, nor when you end up creating the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use callbacks when working with stores (generally when doing ajax calls). In your case your views should either be created when the store finished loading (use the `load` event and let the callback create your view) or create a `adminPanelEnabled()` method that get called by the `load` event of the store.

Both variants have one thing in common, they get executed when the store finished loading.

In addition: if you just need this once you can register the event as sort of singleton

```
store.on('load', function(/*see api for ful arg list*/) {}, scope, { single:true })
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea i created on the application event i created when all stores finished loading.

Comment: In app.js (Sencha ExtJS MVC), I used ... store.on('load', function() { Ext.application( .... });

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you @seba for the idea i created in the consructor

```
    applicationName.getApplication().on('allStoresLoaded', function() {
        console.log(Ext.getStore('Userrights').findExact("name", "admin_panel_access"))

    });
```

And it works now :D

Comment: Can you help me understand what you did?  I'm implementing the same thing in my code, but I don't quite understand how you created your if/then statement to switch the config or where this app.getApplication().on handler call goes?

Comment: It is pretty simple, the application name is the application which you created, like store or no idea what. it is the application you are running. get store on it gets a store and adds an actions on a event which is later handeld properly.